# Using Redis as a distributed internal nodeJS cache

Tags: node.js, caching, redis

Currently I have two load-balanced single-process nodeJS instances on Amazon beanstalk. They each just use a simple in-memory object as a cache. Because they are on different servers, their cache is not shared.

This is where Redis comes in. I want to utilize Redis to create a shared cache, but only to prime the internal memory of NodeJs.

You see, currently I am caching 4KB-10KB objects, if I solely relied on Redis then I have not only the Redis latency to retrieve the obejct but the network latency as well. I rather use Redis as a persistent cache that will prime my nodeJS instances when they are booted up, and also keep both internal caches in sync periodically (every x minutes)

A pretty basic nodeJs memory cache is https://github.com/tcs-de/nodecache

To complicate things even more, I am looking to start using nodeJS cluster ability to fork multiple processes of the application under the same server. Therefore, it is important that all clusters share 1 in-memory local server cache.

The aforementioned nodejs lib has a wrapper that aids the use in a cluster environment : https://github.com/lvx3/cluster-cache

---

To recap,

I will have Server A and server B who will be load balanced evenly. Each server (A&B) will have say 4 nodeJs processes who need to share just 1 cache (That is, the 4 server A nodeJs processes should all use a Server A cache, same for B)

Then I want the Server A and Server B cache to periodically sync and "persist" onto Redis. In the event of a crash or redeployment the Server cache would be primed with what is in Redis.

---

What are my options? Is there any well established solutions or mix of solutions that would be suitable? Such as a plugin like nodecache (simple) that has a Redis plugin? I also use express so perhaps there are express middleware that would be well suited for this.

Is it even worth the complexity to use Redis to prime a local server memory cache or should I just rely solely on Redis and take the network latency hit?

An acceptable but somewhat disappointing time for me to get back a 10KB object is 20 ms. I'd much prefer around 1ms. Redis and the nodeJs servers will be on Amazon so will be pretty close together.

I understand that if I have a redis cache of say 50MB that the same 50MB would exist on Server A and Server B. I am more than willing to spend money on hardware/ram for the benefit of speed.

Comment: to make sure that you can scale later on, maybe you can run redis as an addtional container on the same k8s pod?